# R select data of each row on basis of the row quantiles

Tags: r, select, row, quantile

I have a data set with 60 rows and 3036 columns. I have already calculated the row quantiles with the function `rowQuantiles` from the `matrixStats` package. From this I got a column vector [60,1]. Now, I want to select from each row only the data which is higher than the row quantile. If I use the which function as following:

```
datset_qu95 = which(dataset > rowQuantiles(dataset, probs=c(0.95))
```

then I loose the data dimensions and get only an array instead of a matrix with the following dimensions [60,152].

Can somebody help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Your suggestion shows me only how to calculate the 95 quantile on a other way. But my aim is to select afterwards only the data of each row which is over the row quantile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a rowQuantile function is needed. Just pick out the highest values up to a probability threshold: (edit note (first version had incorrect index expression)

```
> apply( dat, 1, function(x) x[order(x)][1:( (1-0.95)*ncol(dat))])
    obs1     obs2     obs3 
 11.5379 856.3470 136.8860
```

And as always, because R matrices are column oriented, you will probably want to use `t()` on the result to get this back into the row orientation you expect.

To your comment: Fixed it so it picks up the highest values rather than the lowest values:

```
 apply( dat, 1, function(x)
                  x[order(x, decreasing=TRUE)][1:( (1-0.95)*ncol(dat))])
```

Comment: This function does not work as wished because it does not select the data of each row which is higher than the row quantile

Comment: It should now pick up the values higher than the 0.95th row quantile.

Answer (score 0):

`0.05 * 3036 = 151.8` but selecting in each row the values greater than the 95% quantile does not mean that you will have systematically 152 values. If you want to keep your object dimensions you can try to replace undesired values with `NA`'s.
As your object is not huge you could also work with data frame objects and have your observations along the row dimension.

```
library(matrixStats)

# To extract your values...
myfun <- function(k, q){x[k, x[k,] > q]}
x <- matrix(sample(1:100, 60*3036, replace=TRUE), ncol=3036)
xx <- mapply(myfun, seq(along=x[,1]), rowQuantiles(x, probs=.95))
# xx is a list, xx[[1]] contains the values of x[1,] > quantile(x[1, ], .95)

# The number of selected values depends on their distribution - with NORM should be stable
x11() ; par(mfrow=c(2,1))
hist(sample(1:100, 60*3036, replace=TRUE)) # UNIF DISTRIB
n.val <- sapply(xx, length)
hist(n.val, xlab="n.val > q_95%")
abline(v=152, col="red", lwd=5)

# Assuming you want the same number of value for each row
n <- min(n.val)
myfun <- function(x){sample(x, n)} # Representative sample - Ordering is possible but introduce bias. Depends on your goals
xx <- t(sapply(xx, myfun))
dim(xx) # 60 n
```

Comment: A row-oriented function that picks based on an ordering could have exactly 152 items. If the values are selected from a continuous distribution there would be a very small chance of ties, anyway. If dealing with a  distribution having ties in the upper tail, using the `order` function allows you to break the ties in a sensible manner.